# Digital Clock Issue in Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, time

I am new to Kubuntu and I have an issue with the Digital Clock Widget.

First things first:

- I did install NTP
- `datetimectl` does say NTP Sync Yes and the Local Time is correct as well

  ```
  $ timedatectl
  Local time: sáb 2016-02-06 21:30:02 VET
  Universal time: dom 2016-02-07 02:00:02 UTC
  RTC time: dom 2016-02-07 02:00:02
  Time zone: America/Caracas (VET, -0430)
  Network time on: yes
  NTP synchronized: yes
  RTC in local TZ: no
  ```

However, ntpq shows just the following:

```
bbuske@bmstiL1:~$ sudo ntpq -np
```

## remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset      jitter

```
 186.71.75.78    .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 190.15.128.72   .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 146.164.48.5    .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 200.93.227.170  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 91.189.89.199   .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

This is however not the main problem. The main problem is with the **digital clock widget** on the task bar. The hour displayed there, is off **one hour**. Like right now it says 10:52 PM while it is 09:52 PM.

I went into the setting and revised the time zone (VET - Venezuelan Standard Time), which is correct, we also do not have DST and there is no option to enable it.

Now: The strange thing is, that in the settings itself, the time shows correct and is set to auto sync. It appears to be a sole issue with the desktop clock. I have tried the analog widget and the other one and both seem to show the correct time.

So I wonder if there is any way to have this fixed? Is there any way to modify the widget? Or anything else I can try? Of course I could just use the system settings to manually set the time one hour back, then the time would show correct but the system time would then be false. Another solution I found is, set the time to GMT and then in the settings for additional time zones, de-select Caracas / Venezuela and and select a time zone named GMT -4,30. Then I could just change the displayed time on the task bar to that one.

However: I would like to have my general time set to VET not to GMT. In the general time and date settings there is just one Caracas / Venezuela. The additional Options like GMT -4.5 are not present there but only in the widget settings.

I have seen this link [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193233) where someone from Venezuela had the same issues. However, he claimed that this has been fixed which apparently is not the case for me.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: All the `.INIT.` lines in your `ntpq -p` (you do not need `sudo` for `ntpq`) show that clock synchronization is still initializing, What does `date;TZ=PST date;TZ=EST date` show? Is VET the same as PST?

Comment: I know, but it has been on .INIT. for hours... and still is... 

The commands you mentioning both bring up the same time, our VET: 

`bbuske@bmstiL1:~$ date;TZ=PST
sáb feb  6 22:44:09 VET 2016
bbuske@bmstiL1:~$ date;TZ=EST
sáb feb  6 22:44:25 VET 2016`

VET is GMT -4.5 so I think it is EST with 1,5 hours missing... PST is like 2,5h ahead of us.

Comment: It looks to me as if you have two problems: non-working NTP, and possible errors in the timezone definition. If you do `sudo service ntp restart`, does it help (with the `.INIT.` problem)? For the timezone errors, read `man zdump;man -a tzselect;man tzfile`. Since `zdump PST VET` shows the same time, Either `VET` is not what you think it is, or the VET timezone definition is incorrect, or something else

Comment: @waltinator Thanls for the reply. The `sudo service ntp restart`did not help. And yes you are right, apparently the PST and VET time show the same time. That said, it leaves me with two facts / questions: 

1. Why is the time I see in the system settings correct (System Setting -> Time and Date) but shows wrong on the taskbar (only for the digital clock, the other clock widgets do show the time correctly!) and 2. I have checked the Caracas time file and it says the correct value GMT -4.5 so I have no idea why the zdump shows PST and VET the same. 

Also I have no clue whats wrong with the NTP.

Comment: I have run `tzselect`on Venezuela with these results: 

The following information has been given:

Venezuela

Therefore TZ='America/Caracas' will be used.

Local time is now:      dom feb  7 10:54:29 VET 2016.
Universal Time is now:  dom feb  7 15:24:29 UTC 2016.

All this info is correct and matches what is seen on the System Settings page. However, the Taskbar Widget keeps showing the wrong time (1h ahead). I am thinking it might be an issue with that particular Widget... since the others work and system time is correct. 

Still the question remains why the NTP Server keeps saying .init.

Comment: Did you try `sudo service ntp restart`? look at `grep ntp /var/log/syslog`. Could the widget have its own"Daylight Savings Time" choice?

Comment: Yes, it did restart: `Feb  7 10:44:09 bmstiL1 ntp[10869]: ...done.
Feb  7 11:10:37 bmstiL1 ntp[11495]: * Stopping NTP server ntpd
Feb  7 11:10:37 bmstiL1 ntpd[10880]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Feb  7 11:10:37 bmstiL1 ntp[11495]: ...done.
Feb  7 11:10:37 bmstiL1 ntp[11507]: * Starting NTP server ntpd
Feb  7 11:10:37 bmstiL1 ntpd[11515]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Fri Oct 23 16:44:04 UTC 2015 (1)` - I have no idea about the widget, but it's a lofical guess. I do not see anything in the widget settings that allows me to set DST. Just to sync by the web, select timezone and change the way it shows...

Comment: Please edit ( http://askubuntu.com/posts/730680/edit ) your question to add information, select the computer text, and click the "{}"button. This will improve readability..

Comment: Please edit ( askubuntu.com/posts/730680/edit ) your question and add the cut-and-paste, formatted with `{}`, results of

Comment: Oops, comment timed out. 
 
Please edit ( askubuntu.com/posts/730680/edit ) your question and add the cut-and-paste, formatted with {}, results of `gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.indicator.datetime`?

Comment: I set the timezone as the timezone code IC but it displayed UTS time.
I changed it to the string Atlantic/Reykjavik and that worked fine. <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones">List_of_tz_database_time_zones</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find a solution on my own.

First of all, as I have guessed, the issue was not with the system itself, but with the Digital Clock Plasma Widget. I could confirm that, since the system time in the system settings was correct and because the other clock widgets for the analog clock and the written clock were working correctly.

Attempts to find that widgets config or reference file to fix it manually or do some further investigation on the issue remained fruitless.

Today I had an automatic update check done after activating the kde-backtrack apt in Software Center. Promptly the system showed up various updates to KDE. After installing them all, without a reboot the clock was fixed and the visual effects, especially those of the taskbar significantly imporved.

Thanks everyone for attempting to help out.

Cheers.